# Using ember service inside utility function

Tags: ember.js

I have a utility function in ember like so:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { inject: { service }, get } = Ember;

export default function(foo) {
  let bar = service('bar');
  console.log('bar', bar);
  window.bar = bar;
  console.log(
    'get(bar, "name")',
    get(bar, 'name')
  );
  return [foo, bar];
}

// services/bar.js
export default Service.extend({
  name: 'TheSpot'
});
```

The really unfortunate part is this utility function is called by an external library, so I can't just pass in a reference to some ember object's `this`.

Comment: If I got your answer right, you like to use that utility function to return an object containing configuration for localization isn't it? Isn't there any other way to pass that configuration to this external library? It might be helpfull to get more information what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: Indeed there could be a variety of ways to solve any issue, but the thing I'm trying to understand in this question is simply: How do I use an ember service inside a utility function? (Without just passing in a reference to the service)

Comment: To put it simple: You don't. It's bad practice. Utility function should only depend on there input.

Comment: how do you provide this function to the external library?

Comment: The addon imports this utility fn by name

Answer (score -1):

I guess the only thing I can think of doing right now is making the bar service global in the application route init hook.

In the application route:

```
  init(...args) {
    window.appThis = this;
    return this._super(...args);
  },
```

The utility function:

```
export default function(defaultOptions) {

  defaultOptions.lang = {
    thousandsSep: ',',
    rangeSelectorZoom: `${window.appThis.get('i18n').t('zoom')}:`
  };

  return defaultOptions;
}
```

Comment: What are you wanting to accomplish here? Looks like you’re wanting to provide a set of highcharts options externally, including a text value that is localized inside of your Ember app? If so, seems like you could expose your utility function’s results through a separate service that you push to the window object. But once your utility function depends on Ember services it’s no longer a utility function :-)

Comment: That is true, it's not really a utility function, not a really great api provided from highcharts. Given how services are just singletons it just blows me away that they can't just be called like regular plain old functions. Thanks for the ideas acorncom!

Comment: Oh, you could fairly easily call the service as a regular function. In an init somewhere you could retrieve the service in question and store it on the window object. It’d be a tad messy, but definitely doable. You’d reference it as `window.i18n.t()` Quite easy to do, but could get messy over time. But if you’re integrating an Ember app into something else, it’s your best option sometimes ...